# Sorting an array by a private variable

Tags: actionscript-3

So... I have spent the last hour trying to figure out why the sort method for my array was not working properly, when I realized that the variable I was trying to sort by in my objects was not publicly available. I have accessed it by using a getter method, which has worked fine for all other purposes. My questions is: Is it possible to sort by a private variable somehow? Perhaps by using a getter method, but I don't know how that would work syntactically. Or do I just have to make my variable public?

On a slightly related note, is there some way to sort on a variable of an object in a vector using standard methods?

Comment: The answer below worked great. It also wasn't my problem. If anyone else is having a similar problem, the solution to mine was not in the sort method at all. I was just not redisplaying the objects in the sorted order, so it looked like it hadn't sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using get function to sort

```
 var k:Vector.<A> = new Vector.<A>();
 k.push(new A(5));
 k.push(new A(3));
 k.push(new A(7));
 k.push(new A(1));
 k.push(new A(9));

 k.sort(compareFunction);

 private function compareFunction(obj1:Object, obj2:Object, properties:Array = null):int
 {

        var a1:A = obj1 as A;

        var a2:A = obj2 as A;

        if (a1.level > a2.level)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (a1.level < a2.level)
        {
             return -1;
        }
        else
        {
             return 0;
        }

 }



class A {

   private var _level:int;


   public function get level():int
   {
       return _level;
   }

   public function A($level:int) 
   {
       _level = $level

    }
}
```